# Factorising using the factor theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm getting an early start on practicing for the GRE. I'm trying some hard questions because I haven't done maths since high school and need to challenge myself. I'm looking at factor theorem right now.

I'm trying to use the factor theorem to factorise f(x) completely.

My f(x) is x^3 + 2x^2 - 5x - 6

After I've solved this I need to solve the inequality x^3 + 2x^2 - 5x - 6 > 0

---

I have some rather monstrous workings out in front of me and I'm still going.

Am I right in suspecting that I just keep trying to plug different factors in, for example x+1 and so on.

Thank you

Comment: Let $\displaystyle f:=\sum_{i=1}^na_iX^i$ be a polynomial with real coefficients, if $\displaystyle x:=\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$ is a root of $f$, then $a|a_0$ and $b|a_n$. In your case, the only rational roots of $f$ are in $\{-3,-2,-1,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @C.Falcon,  $$ f(2)=?, f(-3)=?$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I just did bad computations, shame on me.

Comment: @C.Falcon That is not true. If you plug numbers from that set into $f$, you will get three rational roots.

Comment: @C.Falcon You mean *integer* coefficients, and one must assume  $\,a,b\,$ coprime to apply the Rational Root Test.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, indeed. You are totally right about that!

Answer (score 1):

If $x=c$ is a root of a polynomial $p(x)$, then $p(x)$ can be divided by $x-c$, which means that $x-c$ will appear as a factor; this is basically the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem).

You can indeed start guessing roots to find factors, but you can avoid having to *randomly guess*. Take a look at the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) for some useful guidelines.

Useful here: if a polynomial $x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$ has an integer root $c$, then this number $c$ is a divisor of the constant term $a_0$.

In your case, for $x^3 + 2x^2 - 5x - 6$, the possible integer roots are the divisors of $6$, so they are among $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 6$. You could check all of these.

For the roots $1$ and $-1$, there's a fast way to check:

- if the sum of all the coefficients is equal to $0$, then $x=1$ is a root and $x-1$ will be a factor;
- if the sum of all the coefficients of the even powers of $x$ is equal to the sum of all the coefficients of the odd powers of $x$, then $x=-1$ is a root and $x+1$ will be a factor.

For $\color{red}{1}x^3 + \color{blue}{2}x^2 \color{red}{-5}x^1 \color{blue}{-6}x^0$, we indeed have $\color{red}{1-5} = \color{blue}{2-6}$, so $x=-1$ is a root and you can perform division as you like (Horner's rule, long division ...) to write:
$$x^3 + 2x^2 - 5x - 6 = (x+1)(x^2+x-6)$$
Now you can continue with $x^2+x-6$, or find the roots (and thus also factors) directly via the formulas for a quadratic equation.